# get 'th' text from collection of th using $.each() in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var thCollection=$(#tablename).find('th');
 $.each(thCollection,function(i,obj){
  // here I want the text of the column header
  // obj.text or obj.html is not working 
 });
```

Comment: I have created a datatable in jquery and now I want to hide some columns based on th names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
var thCollection=$('#tablename').find('th');
$.each(thCollection, function (i, obj) {
  //try to convert obj to jquery object 
   var text = $(obj).text();
 });
```

or you can also use this

```
 thCollection.each(function () {
   var text = $(this).text();
 })
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/untnht4u/2/)